# Lucene 5.2.1 PhraseQuery was indexed without position data cannot run PhraseQuery

Tags: lucene

I receive an exception when I make a research with a `PhraseQuery` on the field named 'content'.
To index this one, I use the `org.apache.lucene.document.TextField` class because this field contains many words.
I use the `FrenchAnalyzer` and `RAMDirectory` class to create the index.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: field "comment" was indexed without position data; cannot run PhraseQuery (phrase=comment:"the skype")
>       at org.apache.lucene.search.PhraseQuery$PhraseWeight.scorer(PhraseQuery.java:301)
>       at org.apache.lucene.search.Weight.bulkScorer(Weight.java:137)
>       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:768)
>       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:485)
>       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:694)
>       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.searchAfter(IndexSearcher.java:410)
>       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:439)
>       at org.memory.LuceneIndexer.wildcardSearchIndex(LuceneIndexer.java:189)
>       at org.memory.Mem_04.main(Mem_04.java:60)

```
idxfld = new TextField(field.getFieldname(),(String) field.getValue(),Field.Store.YES);

PhraseQuery query = new PhraseQuery();
query.setSlop(0);
query.add(new Term("comment","the"));
query.add(new Term("comment","skype"));
System.out.println(query.toString());
int numResults = 1000;
ScoreDoc[] hits = searcher.search(query, numResults).scoreDocs;
```

Can you help me ?
Serge

Answer (score 10):

Check if you have indexed the same field using different field types.

```
document.Add(new TextField("comment", "Lucene rocks, do you agree?", FieldStore.YES);
.
.
document.Add(new StringField("comment", "Sure", FieldStore.YES);
```

The above code will produce an "**IllegalStateException field - was indexed without position data**" error if you run this phrase query

> comment: "Lucene rocks"

So make sure you use TextField consistently. Alternatively, you can also use a custom Field with IndexOption set to **DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS**.

Comment: I used  DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS and it works for me.